# Executing Webdriver script from HTML

Tags: java, javascript, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am creating a frame work for my AUT. I plan to use Webdriver/Java. I am relatively new to Selenium, Java and html programming. I want to implement the framework in following manner.

1. There will be an HTML interface where user can select check boxes
   for the test cases he wants to run.
2. He can submit after making his selection.
3. On submitting the script will be executed.
4. Execution will consist of only selected cases.

My questions are:

- Is anything better than html for point 1? I don't want to use Excel
  as I want this interface to be interactive so that anyone can use the interface, without any knowledge of domain or the script running behind it.
- How should I go about point 3? I would need to start my main function
  and pass the selected 'cases' as an array or something.

Comment: My suggestion to you would be to learn Selenium first.  Automation should be approached as a programming activity, not a record-playback activity for long term.  What you could do, is start out with a fleshed framework [like this one](http://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium) and maybe add a keyword system to it.  But honestly running your suite in that manner comes later.  If I were you, stick to basics and use a continuous integration system with your framework until you get more experienced.

Comment: Thank you for the feed back. However, I believe I have already made quite a progress into Selenium with Java programming (I mentioned 'relatively new'). I am already using a data driven frame work, but I need to upgrade it as it is presenting a lot of limitations with respect to my AUT. After a lot of considerations I came to conclusion that the most efficient method for my AUT would be the one I described in question. So thanks once again for your concern, but it would be much better if you could answer the question.

Comment: In another vein, after further research I found out, that I could use AWT or swing for point 1. Looking into it right now. Would update if I succeed :)

Comment: There are couple of suggestions, automation is meant to blur the need to human intervention for running the scripts. Hence most of the frameworks are designed that way. I would suggest have a look at TestNG...incase if u need to select tests then u can modify XML readily to select which tests to run.

Comment: No human intervention, I just want to select the cases at the start of the run. I have 100s of cases, so modifying XML each time, I have to run this weekly in each sprint, it wont do me much good. Anyway thanx for suggestion.

Comment: @MHH did you get anywhere with it?? I am also trying something similar.

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at Selinium IDE? It's a basic front end for Selinium. You can record and playback test cases and you are able to select which test case to run from a test suite.

Since recently this could be used to run tests in browsers other than just firefox using Selenium IDE.

PS
You should also look into [Huxley-Selenium](https://github.com/facebook/huxley) for regression testing. We found the [node version](https://github.com/chenglou/node-huxley) is much easier to install.

Hope this helps. Good luck!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanx for reply. This wont do for me. I have various logical flows in almost each of my test case which is much efficient in normal java based code. Moreover data set is also extensive, which I am currently handling through xls reader. So I will have to build something to meet my exact needs. Maybe I am going wrong way about it, but I am working on it and may be something simpler figures out. PS huxley seems more suited for UI regression which is not my requirement.